# Chopping Off the last Number for a Double

Tags: c++

If I have a double:  732734

How can I return 73273   <---- notice the loss of the '4'

Comment: divide the number by 10 ?

Comment: and floor it...  also, use a steak knife.

Comment: What have you tried? Thought about? Any ideas at all? Effort? SO is not intended to be a replacement brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by 10 and then floor it to remove the decimals:

```
number = floor(number / 10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this somewhere. It removes the last digits after decimal. Not the actual solution but this might give you some hint:

```
int main(){
    for (int a=0;a<80;a++)
        printf(".");
    printf("%2.0f\n",1024.48);
    printf("%2.0f\n",4.48);
    for (int a=0;a<80;a++)
        printf(".");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
................................................................................
1024
4
................................................................................
```